# Trying to pass values from jsp to servlets

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp file `discussion_new.jsp` through which I am trying to pass parameters to a servlet named `DiscussionServlet`, but the values are not getting passed, please help, I am attaching the following code.

Here is `discussion_new.jsp`:

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center"> Start a New Discussion</h1>
  <div id="right-container">
<form action="DiscussionServlet" method="post">
       <br>
     <h1 align="left">Discussion Title</h1>
  <textarea name="post-title" id="post-title" rows ="1" cols="90" height="50"   
    width="200">
                  </textarea>
            <h1 align="left">Discussion Content</h1>
   <textarea name="post-detail" id="post-detail" rows="18" cols="90" height="50" 
     width="200">
  </textarea>

<input id="button-submit" type="submit" value="Post" onclick="return confirm('Do                
      you really want to make this post?');" name="submit"/>        
     </form>
  </div>

   </body>
    </html>
```

And here is the `Servlet` code:

```
@WebServlet(name = "DiscussionServlet", urlPatterns = {"/DiscussionServlet"})
public class DiscussionServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    HttpSession s=request.getSession();
   String u_id= (String) s.getAttribute("u_id");
   String post_title=request.getParameter("post-title");
   String post_detail=request.getParameter("post-detail");


    PreparedStatement p1=null;
    try {
         Connection c1=ConnectionClass.getConnected();
         p1=c1.prepareStatement("insert into     
     discuss(id,disc_title,disc_content)values(?,?,?)");
         p1.setString(1, u_id);
         p1.setString(2, post_title);
         p1.setString(3, post_detail);    
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}


   @Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
}
```

There is no error with the sql syntax and attribute values, I have checked, and I have removed the extra comments also from the code . Hope somebody helps

Answer (score 0):

You code looking fine, please to confirm that you getting post data in your servlet print values to console like this 

    `String post_title=request.getParameter("post-title");
    String post_detail=request.getParameter("post-detail");
    System.out.println(post_title);
    System.out.println(post_detail);`

and check you console either you getting value or not

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect and also the values are passed to the servlet, only mistake which i think u made is u are tring to insert received values into database but the p1.executeUpdate() is missing so if u want the received value to be stored in the database include p1.executeUpdate() it will work fine...........!

Comment: @Jaitheradevi-Yes, I tried it and it works now, I will not make this mistake again.

Comment: @Bills- Yes, I tried printing the values and it was being passed, i had actually not written p1.executeUpdate(), that is why it was not working.